# Xamarin forms Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 Application can't debug (VS2013 ultimate update 5)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, silverlight-4.0, xamarin.forms

When I trying Debug Xamain forms application target windows phone 8.1 (device or simulator) silverlight application, but always output this error and end the debug mode. 
Anyone got idea how to fix this?

OS: windows 8.1 pro
IDE: visual studio 2013 ultimate update 5
Project: Xamarin forms windows phone 8.1 project

I have try another PC, same code but vs2013 update 4, it can run very well but some how I don't know why, it also appear this issues just now.

```
AéHost.exe’ (CoreCLR: Silverliéht AppDomain): Loaded lCIKwindows\system32KWinMetadataKWindows.winmd’. Cannot-find or open the PDB file.
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded lCI\DataKProgramsK{7AACo885n84A3u4FFE-B677-3218599B3691}\Install\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8.DLL’.
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded lCI\DataKProgramsK{7AACo885n84A3u4FFE-B6??-3218599B3691}\Install\CrossPlatform.DLL’. Symbols loade
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded ’C:\DataKProgramsK{?    AA50885*84A3“4FFE-B6??-3218599B3691}KInstallKXamarin.Forms.Core.DLL’. Module w
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded lCI\windowsKsystem32KSystem.Runtime.ni.dll’. Symbols loaded.
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded lCIKwindowsKsystem32KSystem.UbjectModel.ni.dll’. Symbols loaded.
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded lCIKwindowsKsystem32KSystem.Collections.ni.dll’. Symbols loaded.
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded lCI\windowsKsystem32KSystem.Linq.ni.dll’. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type System.Io.FileNotFoundException occurred in CrossPlatform.WinPhone.DLL
AgHost.exe’ (CoreCLR:Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded lCI\windowsKsystem32Ken-USKmscorlib.debug.resources.dll’. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type lSystem.Reflection.TargetInvocationException’ occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type lSystem.Reflection.TargetInvocationException’ occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll
The program ’[5328] AgHost.exe’ has exited with code -1 (Uxffffffff).
Package Manager Console Error List Output
```

Answer (score 0):

After long time investigate, I found out that the windows phone 8.1 SDK isn't install correctly, for those who still have this kind of problem, please check your visual studio components.